# In ReactJS toggle images in a child component from a parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, toggle

I have a parent component, RoutineDashboard, with a child component, . The child component has two props, image and checked, which are both images. I only want one of the images to show at a time. How can I use the button in the child component to toggle between the images in  from the parent component?

```
import react, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, NavLink, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import TaskCard from '../../Components/TaskCard';
import socks from '../../Images/iPhone 11 Pro/socks.svg';
import check from '../../Images/iPhone 11 Pro/check.svg';

class RoutineDashboard extends Component {
    
    state = {
        tasks: 4,
        completeTasks: 0
    }

  
    
    updateTaskCountHandler (className) {}
 

        
    
    render () {
      
        
        

    return (
        <div>
              <div  className="Container">  
                <div className="Tasks">
                    <TaskCard clicked={() => this.updateTaskCountHandler("task1")} className="task1" image={socks} check={check} title={'Get Dressed'}/>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    }
}

export default RoutineDashboard;
```

Below is the child component  :

```
import react from 'react';
import { Route, NavLink, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import './TaskCard.css';
import star from '../Images/iPhone 11 Pro/star.svg';
import check from '../Images/iPhone 11 Pro/check.svg';
// import bed from '../Images/iPhone 11 Pro/bed.svg';


function TaskCard (props) {


    function toggleCheck () {
        
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="TaskCard">
                <div className="card w-100">
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <div className="TaskItems">
                            <img src={props.image}></img>
                            <img src={star}></img>
                            
                            <h5 className="card-title">{props.title}</h5>
                                <a href="#" id={props.id} className="btn btn-primary" onClick={()=>props.clicked()}>Done</a>
                                <img id="check" className="Check" src={check}></img>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TaskCard;
```

Comment: I assume when you click the 'Done' link in the child component, you get an error?

Comment: Technically I would but I would like to use that button to instantiate a function that would then toggle between the two images. I will be using the <TaskCard/> component many times and want to toggle the image just for that given component.

Comment: If you want to toggle between two images within a <TaskCard/> component, why not just control the state there?

Comment: Well, there is other logic in the parent component that is being called on when that button is clicked in the updateTaskCountHandler that was excluded for clarity of the question and I was attempting to include the logic for the toggle in that function as well as I am not sure how to call a function In the parent and one in the child upon the clicking of one button. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: In regards to _'I am not sure how to call a function In the parent and one in the child upon the clicking of one button'_, call the `toggleCheck()` method in the `TaskCard` link `onClick` attribute and call `props.clicked()` inside the `toggleCheck()` method. This way you call both

Comment: oh great thanks! I will try that. I did want to handle the toggle inside of the child component and now I think I will be able to do this.

Comment: I got this to work based on the comments.

Comment: Good to hear you got it to work!

Comment: @BenRondeau I did semi-get it to work. It does toggle the image but then only does it for one of the TaskCard components in the parent if I have multiple. I added in more TaskCard components and now it toggles for one then no longer works for the other...should I be using ID somehow?

Comment: Do you have a repo you could share of your code? Then I could take a look and let you know what changes are needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a boolean variable to state and show the images based on this variable value.
You can also change its value when pressing the button.

Comment: Ill make one quickly and share the link!